# Find the most common String in an ArrayList - currently returns null

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I am pretty new to java. I have been researching how to find the most common String in an array, and my code isn't working as it should. My error is that `mostCommon` prints out `null` when I need it to print out the most frequent IP address.

This is my code...

```
public class Log_File_Analysis 
{

private static ArrayList<String> ipAddress = new ArrayList<>();
private static String temp , mostCommon;
int max = 0,  num = 0;


public String getMostUsedIpAddress()
{
     Collections.sort(ipAddress);   
    for (String string : ipAddress) 
    {
      if (string.equals(temp)) 
      {
        num++;
      } 
      else {
        if (num>max) 
        {
          max = num;
          mostCommon = string;
        }
        num = 1;
        temp = string;
      }
    }
    return mostCommon;
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a log file to be analyized");
    //Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    File filename = new File("small.log");              
    try
    {   
        Scanner data_store = new Scanner (filename);
        while(data_store.hasNext())
        {
            String line = data_store.nextLine(); 
            int begin = line.indexOf("[client ") + 8;
                int end = line.indexOf("]", begin);
            String ip = line.substring(begin, end);
            ipAddress.add(ip);
            System.out.println(ip);
        }
        data_store.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("small.log was not found!");         
    }
    System.out.println(mostCommon);
}

}
```

Could you please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: it doesn't look like `getMostUsedIpAddress` is ever called

Comment: You should also make it `static` if you want to call it from `main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere in your code are you actually calling your method to determine the most common value.

You need to add this to the end of your `main()` method...

```
mostCommon = getMostUsedIpAddress();
System.out.println(mostCommon);
```

Basically, you've finished reading in all the values, so now you need to call your method to find the most common value, then you can display it. At present, your code is printing `null` because you haven't actually tried to set the value of `mostCommon` anywhere.

Comment: this won't work since `getMostUsedIpAddress` is an instance method

Comment: @WATTO Studios Thank you!! I don't know how i missed that lol :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be calling your getMostUsedIpAddress method.

Try changing 
System.out.println(mostCommon);
To
System.out.println(getMostUsedIpAddress());

Since you are returning mostCommon and not setting it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialise the two Strings temp and mostCommon.
The can be the main problem!
They are usually initialised like String temp = ""; if they have no content (it is like initialising an int value to 0);